# What is AuthorizeEndpointPath?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm building an ASP.NET WebApi SPA using OWIN middleware and need an explanation of what the **AuthorizeEndpointPath** property does in OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions.

The documentation states

> The request path where client applications will redirect the user-agent in order to obtain user consent to issue a token. Must begin with a leading slash, like "/Authorize".

When I try to access a protected WebApi without a Bearer token, my application never redirects to the path specified (as I would expect), but simply returns a 401.

Comment: Still no response: please let me know if my question is unclear and I'll reword it or provide more details.

Answer (score 29):

The different endpoint paths are for use with different OAuth flows for token granting.

- `TokenEndpointPath` = used to get tokens, in the *client credentials grant* flow, the *resource owner password credentials grant* flow, and at the end of an *authorization code grant* flow
- `AuthorizeEndpointPath` = used for delegated auth in the *authorization code grant* flow and *implicit grant* flow

Calling either of these endpoints will result in the execution of various methods in your implementation of `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` - which ones are executed depends on which endpoint you called, and which parameters you sent with the request.  You have to call one of them explicitly from your client - you'll never get redirected to either of them.

Before discussing the flows and endpoints further lets first define three things:

- *Authorization server*: the thing that we are making calls to to authorize the client or the user.  In your case - the WebApi web service that you're configuring for OAuth.  Quite frequently this is also the same thing that is actually serving up the resources, but the resource server and the authorization server can be split out.
- *Client*: the thing that is making the request to the authorization server, either on behalf of itself or on behalf of a user.  Could be a mobile app, a SPA, a web app, or simply another application with no actual users.
- *User*: the user of some client application

### TokenEndpointPath

#### *Client credentials grant* flow

We're letting the client authenticate directly - we're not asking a user to input a username and password anywhere.  This might be because the client doesn't have users, or we don't care who the user is when we call the web service.

Example request:

```
POST https://yourwebapi.com/token HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: yourwebapi.com

grant_type=client_credentials&
client_id=mega_app&
client_secret=1234hsdflkjh123
```

Will call `GrantClientCredentials` (having validated the client id in `ValidateClientAuthentication`) for you to set up some claims about the client.

#### *Resource owner password credentials* flow

This is when the user enters their details directly into the client, and the client sends these details directly to the authorization server.  So **the client sees the user's credentials**.

You'd call it in your client with a request something like this:

```
POST https://yourwebapi.com/token HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: yourwebapi.com

grant_type=password&
username=bart&
password=b4rt
```

The client makes a request to the endpoint you have specified in  `TokenEndpointPath`, with grant_type of password, this will result in a call to the `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method in your implementation of `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider`.

Assuming the user credentials are valid, access is granted, you create an identity that will have some claims specific to that user, and a token is returned that the client can subsequent send to the authorization server to pull this identity out again on later requests.

### AuthorizeEndpointPath

For *authorization code grant* flow and *implicit grant* flow we're interested in who the user is, but we don't want the user entering credentials directly into the client.  In this case, the client calls through to the authorization server and it's the authorization server that gets the user to authenticate in some way, on behalf of the client.  In this case the client has to send through its client id and a redirect_url and some other bits.

```
  GET  HTTP/1.1
  Host: https://yourwebapi.com/api/Account/ExternalLogin?
  client_id=mega_app&
  scope=user+repo&
  state=1234kjhsfdlkh123497&
  response_type=code&
  redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fyourwebapi.com%2fcallme
```

The `response_type` parameter determines whether we're using *implicit* or *authorization code* flow.  In `AuthorizationEndpointResponse` based on this we can return either the token or the code.  If we return a code, then the client has to make a call to the `TokenEndpointPath` with that code to be given a token.

---

Have a look at [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.oauth.oauthauthorizationserverprovider_methods%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) for more info, and also Chapter 16 of [Designing Evolvable Web APIs with ASP.NET](http://webapibook.net/).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here looking for the same answer. And since I didn't find any I started digging with the decompiler.

It turns out the `OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware` is using either `TokenEndpointPath` or `AuthorizeEndpointPath` to match the current request URI and see if it is an authentication attempt. In the case it matches the `AuthorizeEndpointPath` it creates a new `AuthorizeEndpointRequest` using the parameters from `this.Request.Query` that should include values like `client_id` and `redirect_uri`.

So my guess is that a request to the `AuthorizeEndpointPath` should look like

```
/api/Account/ExternalLogin?client_id=<your_server_id>&redirect_uri=<absolute_path_to_external_authorization_endpoint>
```

and would be, obviously used yo authenticate using a third party server.

Again, this is what I could figure out from the source code.